# [] precedence over * operator

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Somewhere in my code I am doing something very bad. I'm getting undefined behavior in my extrema variable when it does run but most of the time it doesn't even run. Any help would be really great.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_extrema(int quadrant, int **extrema)
{
  if (quadrant == 1)
  {
    *(extrema)[0] = 0;
    *(extrema)[1] = 90;
  }
  else if (quadrant == 2)
  {
    *(extrema)[0] = -90;
    *(extrema)[1] = 0;
  }
}

void print(int* arr)
{
      printf("%i",arr[0]);
      printf(",");
      printf("%i\n",arr[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *extrema = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    get_extrema(1,&extrema);
    print(extrema);
    get_extrema(2,&extrema);
    print(extrema);
}
```

I also tried editing the extrema array using pointer arithmetic like the following:

```
**(extrema) = 0;
**(extrema+1) = 90;
```

But that did not work either. I really have no clue where this is going wrong and I could really use some help.

Comment: printf("%s",arr[0]); is suspect. %s is for strings.

Comment: @Bathsheba good point. That was a mistake in my copying over.

Comment: @philaeton ;-) that's one less UB point

Comment: @Bathsheba:- That is a possible answer!!! I guess you should post this as an answer!! :)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The original issue was in the Arduino IDE on Windows 7. Then I ran this smaller code on gcc in Windows 7 and still got the answer.

Comment: @RahulTripathi ;-) Only a partial answer at best and all I have time for whilst recompiling a load of C++. A complete answer will involve changing the function prototype to something less obscure and also dropping arcane dereferencing.

Comment: Why are you passing an `int**` instead of an `int*` to `get_extrema`? It's not an error, but isn't it unnecessary?

Comment: @thejh To edit the array don't I need to pass a pointer to the array like I did?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. You'd only need that if you wanted to change the value of `extrema` in the main function, not if you just want to alter the values it points to.

Comment: @phileaton: If you copy-and-paste your code, you can avoid most transcription errors.

Comment: see my more perfect answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you get undefined behavior is that the subscript operator `[]` takes precedence over the indirection operator `*`. The value of `extrema` is indexed as an array of pointers, which is incorrect, because there's only a single pointer there.

Since you are passing a pointer to a pointer, you need to put the asterisk inside parentheses:

```
if (quadrant == 1)
{
    (*extrema)[0] = 0;
    (*extrema)[1] = 90;
}
else if (quadrant == 2)
{
    (*extrema)[0] = -90;
    (*extrema)[1] = 0;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/L1EqUY)

Answer (score 1):

`a[b]` is equal to `*(a + b)`, but has higher precedence than the `*`. (And like `a + b` is `b + a`, so is `a[b]` equal to `b[a]`; and `5[a]` equal to `a[5]`).

Thus:

```
*(extrema)[1] = 90;

// is equal to
*(*(extrema + 1)) = 99;

// When what you want to do is 
*((*extrema) + 1) = 99;

// which is of course equal to
(*extrema)[1] = 99;
```

However, an even better question is: why are you using the double pointer, when it is not **needed**.

```
void get_extrema(int quadrant, int *extrema)
{
    if (quadrant == 1)
    {
        extrema[0] = 0;
        extrema[1] = 90;
    }
    else if (quadrant == 2)
    {
        extrema[0] = -90;
        extrema[1] = 0;
    }
}

void print(int *arr)
{
     printf("%i,%i\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *extrema = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof (int));

    get_extrema(1, extrema);
    print(extrema);

    get_extrema(2, extrema);
    print(extrema);
}
```